# How can owl:equivalentClass be defined in terms of owl:symmetricProperty, rdfs:subPropertyOf, and rdfs:subClassOf?

Tags: owl, rdfs

In reading the book `Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist` I have come across an example that I cannot wrap my head around.

`owl:equivalenceClass` can be defined in terms of these two triples:

```
owl:equivalentClass rdf:type owl:symmetricProperty.
owl:equivalentClass rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:subClassOf.
```

I could use help understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first triple says that if a property `P` is a `owl:symmetricProperty` than we can infer the triple `P owl:inverseOf P`.

The second triple says that if a property `P` is a subPropertyOf `Q` then from `A P B` we can infer `A Q B`.

If a class `C` is a subclass of `D` then from `x rdf:type C` we can infer `x rdf:type D`.
Now lets put it all together with `owl:equivalentClass`:

Because `owl:equivalentClass` is a `rdfs:subPropertyOf` `rdfs:subClassOf` then whenever we have `A owl:equivalentClass B` we can infer `A subClassOf B`, and because `owl:equivalentClass` is a symmetricProperty we can also infer `B subClassOf A`.

Comment: This is correct but also feels like unnecessary complication - equivalent classes in OWL are defined as (two or more) classes that are subclasses of each other, so you can represent the same semantic model with one equivalent class triple and this definition of the equivalent class property, to let an RDF reasoner draw the inferences, or just serialise as two subclass triples and get the same result out - likely faster because reasoners know how to treat subclass axioms efficiently. It would also show up as an owl profile violation if you want to use the ontology in an owl reasoner.

Comment: And in an owl reasoner the triples add nothing - so this helps only for rdf reasoners. But, why use an owl property if the reasoning will be only in rdf?